# Sending gmail to gmail message using smtplib python

Tags: python, email, gmail, smtplib

```
email_user = 'sender@gmail.com'
email_pass = 'password'
SMTP_URL = "smtp.gmail.com:587"

def send_email(price):    
    try:
        s = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_URL)
        s.ehlo()
        s.starttls()
        s.ehlo()
        s.login(email_user, email_pass)
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        print("Failed to login")
    else:
        print("Logged in! Composing message..")
        msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
        msg["Subject"] = "Subject"
        msg["From"] = email_user
        msg["To"] = 'recipient@gmail.com'
        text = "Hello recipient"
        part = MIMEText(text, "plain")
        msg.attach(part)
        s.sendmail(email_user, email_user, msg.as_string())
        print("Message has been sent.")
```

I'm using the above script to send an email from sender@gmail.com to recipient@gmail.com (both owned by me). The weird thing that happens is - I see the email in sender@gmail.com's Sent folder, but the email isn't received by recipient@gmail.com (I checked the spam folder as well). Anyone experienced this before? Know a solution?

Comment: `s.sendmail(email_user, email_user, msg.as_string())` you are sending mail to the same user. it should be `s.sendmail(from_user,to_user , msg.as_string())` . (https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail)

Comment: Thank you mchackam! This worked. I didn't realize the bug because the sent mail in my sender@gmail.com had the right recipient address.